# Stop Excel from converting Date to Number

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet A.xls with 5 columns. One of the headers is Aug-15. When I change the `Aug` to `Sep` Excel re-formats to: `15-Sep`.

When I click on General it shows a value of `42262` thus when I extract the cell-value using Python, it returns `42262`.

How can I retain the formatting as Sep-15 so it returns `Sep-15`?
Where is it actually doing this conversion in Excel?

Comment: Use the Excel TEXT mask
TEXT(A1,"mmm-dd")

Answer (score 20):

Just place an apostrophe at the beginning:

```
'Aug-15
```

The apostrophe will not display in the cell. It forces Excel to treat what follows at text.

Comment: Learnt this new :)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the cell and go to format cells. There you can define the cell format.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did all that kind of manipulation already, but it converts it back to the number..hence the post here.

Comment: Thank you, it works in practice, but when reading it back as a value, its not a plain read without manipulating the "'". So didnt go with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

[This Link,](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e)
Then all you have to do is paste the cell format to the whole column (Select the cell, then click the paint brush, then click the column letter.)

If it doesn't help, please explain how you are changing the cell content, manually, VBA, Python.. must be related to this..

Comment: Try adding code snippet as link might be broken in future.

Comment: Thank you for the link - I do know how to format cells and use the various options for dates-never ran into this problem before. Where it converts the date to a number. BTW, I'm manually copying the value. I cannot apply the format to the entire column since only this header is a Date and rest are numbers.

Comment: You are manually copying or PASTING the value? If you paste the value on the cell (Like Ctrl + V) you are pasting the cell formating along with the data, try to paste it Using Alt + C + V + V Or just "Paste -> Value"